# How do I know if my iOS Safari content blocker is enabled?

Tags: ios, safari-content-blocker

Is there an iOS API that would tell me if my content blocker for Safari is enabled? Or do I have to resort to some kind of heuristics if I want to know that?

Answer (score 2):

Have been wondering the same question and eventually came up with this method:
break the structure of your `.json` file and see if you get an error in debuger. If you do - everything is fine and you should revert your `.json` to the normal state and carry on.