# Determine if user has enabled application's Safari content blocker extension

Tags: ios, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, safari-content-blocker

I'm working on a [Safari Content Blocking extension](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-511/). I intend to show setup instructions if the extension is disabled and to show settings if it is conversely enabled. How can I determine if the extension is enabled by the user?

I've seen [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675628/how-to-detect-whether-custom-keyboard-is-activated-from-the-keyboards-container/25714326#25714326) to detect if a custom keyboard is activated but there's no key on `NSUserDefaults` that relates to Safari Content Blockers.

Comment: Looks like this isn't exposed as a public API yet.  If you are working in a Jailbroken environment, there might be a plist or file with that info in `/var/mobile/Media/Safari/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32970259/how-do-i-know-if-my-ios-safari-content-blocker-is-enabled

Comment: break the structure of your `.json` file and see if you get an error in `debugger`. If you do - everything is fine and you should revert your `.json` to the normal state and carry on.

Comment: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/safari-content-blocking-ios9 this should be of some help. Please feel free to get back.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As of iOS 10, there is a new method in [`SFContentBlockerManager`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfcontentblockermanager/) to support this:

**[`getStateOfContentBlocker(withIdentifier:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/safariservices/sfcontentblockermanager/1639499-getstateofcontentblocker)**

And you call it like this (Swift 3):

```
SFContentBlockerManager.getStateOfContentBlocker(withIdentifier: "your.identifier.here", completionHandler: { (state, error) in
    if let error = error {
        // TODO: handle the error
    }
    if let state = state {
        let contentBlockerIsEnabled = state.isEnabled
        // TODO: do something with this value
    }
})
```

Comment: hi bro, i am going to create subscription based app i want programatically enabled and disabled blocker its possible or not ?

Comment: @Rock: You cannot change the enabled/disabled state in Safari's Content Blocker settings programmatically. Only the user can change it via the Settings app.

Answer (score 7):

You could utilize a `SFSafariViewController` to load a custom website. This website checks whether it is able to show something that your content blocker should block. Then redirect to the respective custom url (success/failure) that your app previously registered for. You could even use a hidden Safari View Controller without animation to avoid any distraction from the user's perspective (as shown [here](https://library.launchkit.io/how-ios-9-s-safari-view-controller-could-completely-change-your-app-s-onboarding-experience-2bcf2305137f)). (I guess this technique is used by former content blocker [Peace](https://peace.land))

### Steps

#### App

1. Register custom URLs for success/failure
2. Register for notification callback using the NotificationCenter  (e.g.
   `contentBlockerEnabled`)
3. Use `SFSafariViewController` to show a custom website and include the following rule in `blockerList.json`:

   ```
   {
       "action": {
           "type": "css-display-none",
           "selector": ".blocked_selector"
       },
       "trigger": {
           "url-filter": ".*"
       }
   }
   ```

#### Website

4. [Check for blocked content](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-detect-ads-block/):

   ```
   if($('.blocked_selector').css('display') == "none") {
      // Content blocker enabled
   }
   ```
5. Redirect to custom URL (success/failure)

#### App

6. Post notification from
   `application:openURL:options:` (success/failure based on called url)

## Update 18/01

Following on from [Tilo's hypothesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33626107/1095883), I built the proposed solution. I wrote about what [I learnt on Medium](https://medium.com/@brod_ie/is-your-app-s-safari-content-blocker-enabled-c6df7e478b38#.hrz9xovzs) and you can grab [the source files from GitHub](https://github.com/ryanbrodie/IsContentBlockerEnabled).

**TL;DR** It works but only temperamentally due to the latency incurred of the content blocking rules database to update. A potential workaround is redirecting the test page to create an artificial delay.

Comment: How do you check for blocked content on the custom site?

Comment: A possible solution is described here (using jQuery):  http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/jquery-detect-ads-block/

Comment: Right I've tidied up the answer and it looks very promising. I won't be able to verify tonight but for the sake of the bounty I've marked this as correct.